# Cannot Get usb to boot in windows 8

Tags: windows

I have created the USB stick with Pen drive linux USB installer, and have disabled secure boot and selected the stick to be the bootable source, but it still goes to Windows 8 instead of USB installed with Ubuntu. I am having the hardest time with this, please help!

Comment: Did you download 64 bit version? Some also have issues with certain installers, certain flash drives and certain USB ports. Try other ports, try different installers, verify that download is correct with md5sum. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM  Many do use pendrive, but rufus and unetbootin are other alternatives. Has instructions for installing - http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a forum question, because I think it'll take some back and forth.  Often, issues with booting to USB are related to BIOS settings.  It could be that you just need to rearrange to boot order.  Sometimes, even though USB is available as an option, the machine just won't (these same machines sometimes won't boot to CD, either).  The only way I've been able to reliably boot to USB is if I created the boot drive with UNetBootin, and have set the boot order properly.  Sometimes a cheating way to tell if the machine will recognize it is to shut down windows with the usb active ... sometimes windows will give you an error to let you know you still have a "disk" in the "drive."  Depending on how it's booting, you may also want to check the bootloader (ie: grub) to see if the timer is set to zero with the other operating system as default.